# How to create a lightbox like this

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am pretty new to html + css, and have just coded my first website. What I wanted to ask you is how can I create a jquery lightbox like this: http://0.s3.envato.com/files/2312958/screenshot_01.jpg with its own loading progress view while it loads the image?

Please remember I am new to html!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you want to code it yourself to get some experience? Or do you want to implement it on a website? If it's the latter, there are a lot of wonderful options out there: I would recommend Fancybox (http://fancybox.net/).

Comment: ColorBox is also nice. http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like fancy box. Fancy box is (IMHO) the best lightbox out there. Very reliable and very versatile. Go here for info and examples:

http://fancybox.net/

Go here for usage:

http://fancybox.net/howto

Answer (score 0):

there are any number of lightbox plugins available.

here is a single page showing 10 of them for starters;

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts